# GetGUIThreadInfo() fails on non-foreground thread

Tags: api, winapi, msdn

According to MSDN:

To get the window with the keyboard focus on the foreground queue or the queue of another thread, use the [GetGUIThreadInfo function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633506(v=vs.85).aspx).

If I call GetGUIThreadInfo, passing 0 as a thread ID, i get the window that has the keyboard focus in the foreground thread. What I want to achieve is to know what window has the keyboard focus on ***NON-FOREGROUND*** thread. To do this, I pass the thread ID of the thread I want to "investigate", but GetGUIThreadInfo() returns all zeros. If I make that thread a foreground thread (I.E. activate the window) - then GetGUIThreadInfo() works as intended.

Is there a way to get the information I want - i.e. the window with keyboard focus that is not in the foreground thread?

EDIT:
Foreground thread - a thread owning a foreground Window. Basically a thread which is attached to hardware input queue and the one which is receiving messages when I click the buttons, move mouse, etc. Likewise - non foreground thread is any thread that owns windows but is not attached to the hardware input queue.

Comment: What do you mean with foreground thread and background thread?

Comment: The MSDN article is quite specific that the function will fail if the thread doesn't have a message queue.  Sounds like a match to me.  Pay attention to the return value, use GetLastError() to get the error code.

Comment: A non-foreground thread does not have focus. When a thread loses foreground, it also loses focus.